# Is ADJ a Topos?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

I am reading the fascinating book CWM by MacLane (2nd edition). On page 103, he defines, via a theorem, the composition of adjoints; and on the following page he defines the category "ADJ" whose objects are all small categories and whose arrows are the adjunctions.

My 1st question: is ADJ an elementary topos?

- If yes: what is the interpretation of its subobject-classifier?
- If no: which property of an elementary topos does it fail to have?

My 2nd question: if ADJ is not an elementary topos, is ADJ_TOPOS an elementry topos? (where by ADJ_TOPOS, I mean the category of all small topoi as objects and adjunctions as arrows)

- If yes: what is the interpretation of its subobject-classifier?
- If no: which property of an elementary topos does it fail to have?

Thanks.

Comment: Categories of categories are morally 2-categories, so we should not expect them to be 1-topoi.

Comment: Right. My understanding of higher order categories/topoi is limited. But from my limited knowledge, I thought every n-category is a category (forgetting about higher order stucture). For example, forgetting about vertical composion in a 2-category yeilds category. In that sense I thought I could wonder if ADJ is a topos or not. But Mark's answer below makes sense (with the help of Zhen Lin and Giuseppe I understood my mistake in interpreting Mark's answer).

But your comment is interesting too. On a different topic: is it true that any n-category is a category?

Answer (score 5):

This category doesn’t have a terminal object.

Suppose we had a terminal object $T$. Consider some category $J$ with at least one object. Then there exists a functor $J \to T$, so $T$ has at least one object.

On the other hand, consider the category $0$ with no objects. There exists a functor $T \to 0$, so $T$ must have no objects. Contradiction.

Comment: Thanks Mark. But I am a bit puzzled by your answer in the following aspects:

1) If $T$ is a terminal object and $0$ is the empty category, how do we conclude that there exists a functor from $T$ to $0$?

2) If your argument was true, then even $SET$ could not be a topos.

3) the category ADJ above has as arrows adjuctions, not naked functors.

Am I missing something?

Comment: An adjunction consists of a pair of functors etc.

Comment: Right. But that wasn't the main issue I had with Mark's answer. The main issue for me is (1) in my comment. Why does Mark, seemingly trivially, assume that there exists a functor from $T$ to the empty category (which serves as the main step in his proof by contradiction). That logic is flawed to me. For example, if I want to make same argument for the category of all small sets, then a singleton cannot be a terminal object following Mark's logic.

Comment: @MarlexBlank by assumption you have a functor $\varnothing \to T$, now take its adjoint, which must exists by definition. Another way to see that this category cannot have a terminal object is that the existence of a terminal object is equivalent to the fact that every small category is contractible, which is false.

Comment: Aaah. Thanks. Got it.